# Does smoke stop the Blobber's blobs from exploding?

Tags: into-the-breach

So, I have a situation where there's a blob that's about to blow up and take out literally all the mission objectives AND a building. So, it occurs to me that the exploding counts as an attack, and smoke prevents attack. I have the ability to put smoke on the blob.

Will this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep. The blobs' explosion is an attack, which is canceled by smoke like any other attack.